# Matplotlib 2D histogram seems transposed

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have the following code to plot a 2d histogram in pyplot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MIN, MAX, num = .001, 5000, 500
minn=1
maxx=1000
zbins = 10 ** np.linspace(np.log10(MIN), np.log10(MAX), num)
x=np.linspace(100,600,50000)
y=np.linspace(0,500,50000)

fig1 = plt.figure(1)
counts1,xedges1,edges1,d=plt.hist2d(x,y,bins=zbins)
mesh1 = plt.pcolormesh(zbins, zbins, counts1)
plt.xlim([minn, maxx])
plt.ylim([minn, maxx])
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.gca().set_yscale("log")
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Apologies for my horrible variable naming!

Anyways, when I plot this, the histogram seems to have the x and y axes switched. I checked the matplotlib 2d hist documentation and I was sure that I had the x and y arguments in the right order, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `mesh1 = plt.pcolormesh(zbins, zbins, counts1)` is the line that interchanges the axes (or similar). ...did not investigate further, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

The confusion comes from the fact that the returned `counts` array is not what you think it is.

`plt.hist2d` internally uses [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) to compute the two-dimensional histogram. The documentation states as return values:

> `H` : ndarray, shape(nx, ny)
>   The bi-dimensional histogram of samples x and y. **Values in x are histogrammed along the first dimension and values in y are histogrammed along the second dimension**.
>   `xedges` : ndarray, shape(nx,)
>   The bin edges along the first dimension.
>   `yedges` : ndarray, shape(ny,)
>   The bin edges along the second dimension.

Apart from the fact that there seems to be a [mistake concerning the exact shape of the arrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8979), we see that the first dimension of the returned histogram array is `x` and the second `y`.

However, **matplotlib always expects `y` to be the first dimenstion**. Therefore, while `plt.hist2d` produces the correct plot, `plt.pcolormesh` needs a transposed version of the array.

```
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y, counts.T)
```

A full example, comparing `plt.hist2d` and `plt.pcolormesh`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(1,10,10)
y=np.linspace(6,9,10)

zbinsx= np.linspace(0,10,11)
zbinsy= np.linspace(5,10,6)

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
counts,xedges,yedges,d = ax.hist2d(x,y, bins=[zbinsx,zbinsy])
# counts has shape (10, 5)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xedges,yedges)
mesh1 =ax2.pcolormesh(X,Y, counts.T)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: that is a nice answer!