# Problems with unpacking Matplotlib hist2d outputs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib's function hist2d() and I want to unpack the output in order to further use it. Here's what I do: I simply load with numpy a 2-column file containing my data and use the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np

traj = np.loadtxt('trajectory.txt')
x = traj[:,0]
y = traj[:,1]
M, xe, ye, img = plt.hist2d(x, y, bins = 80, norm = LogNorm())
plt.imshow(M)
plt.show()
```

The result I get is the following:

[image: Result obtained by unpacking the hist2d output and separately plotting the output matrix using imshow]

Instead, if I try to directly plot the hist2d results without unpacking them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np

traj = np.loadtxt('trajectory.txt')
x = traj[:,0]
y = traj[:,1]
plt.hist2d(x, y, bins = 80, norm = LogNorm())
plt.show()
```

I get the whole plot without the strange blue box. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `plt.imshow(M)` plots `M` on the same figure as your 2d hist. Try adding `plt.figure()` just before `plt.imshow(M)` to see what happens

Comment: I would guess that the values in the blue box are maybe above the limit of your colourmap, so maybe greater than 255. Try and normalize the values of `M` to be either between `0` and `1` or integers between `0` and `255`

Comment: @DavidG thanks! This solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a histogram plot directly with `plt.hist2d`. This calculates the histogram and plots it to the current axes. There is no need to show it yet another time using `imshow`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(9)

x = np.random.rayleigh(size=9900)
y = np.random.rayleigh(size=9900)

M, xe, ye, img = plt.hist2d(x, y, bins = 80, norm = LogNorm())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, you may first calculate the histogram and afterwards plot the result as an image to the current axes. Note that the histogram produced by numpy is transposed, see [Matplotlib 2D histogram seems transposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568370/matplotlib-2d-histogram-seems-transposed), making it necessary to call `imshow(M.T)`. Also note that in order to obtain the correct axes labeling, you need to set the `imshow`'s `extent` to the extremal values of the `xe` and `ye` edge arrays.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(9)

x = np.random.rayleigh(size=9900)
y = np.random.rayleigh(size=9900)

M, xe, ye = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = 80)

extent = [xe[0], xe[-1], ye[0], ye[-1]]
plt.imshow(M.T, extent=extent, norm = LogNorm(), origin="lower")

plt.show()
```

[image]