# How to use or manipulate the output (return values) of hist2d and create a new histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to grapple with how to use the return values of hist2d. I see that it returns a 2d array ('a histogram object') as well as bin edges and an image. What I'm trying to do is create two histograms (of some physics data), normalize them, subtract them (i.e. subtract the bin values), and then histogram what's leftover.

One can start with this:

```
h1 = plt.hist2d(x1, y1,bins=(100,100),normed=True)
h2 = plt.hist2d(x2, y2,bins=(100,100),normed=True)
```

The lengths of h1 and h2 are actually 4, with h1[0] being a 2d array with the bin values. It's not clear to me exactly what h1[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM3QL.png),h1[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QywEV.png), and h1[3] are, but subtracting them produces arrays of 0's. I can however, subtract h1[0] and h2[0] and get what looks like meaningful bin values:

```
h1 = plt.hist2d(x1, y1,bins=(100,100),normed=True)
h2 = plt.hist2d(x2, y2,bins=(100,100),normed=True)
H = h1[0] - h2[0]
```

Now, the question is, how can I make a histogram of these new values? I could write over h1[0], but even then, how do I replot the hist2d in the same format without using different types of functions? One can do something similar using histogram2d, and perhaps use a meshgrid but the results come out ugly:

```
h1, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x1, y1,bins=(100,100),normed=True)
h2, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x2, y2,bins=(100,100),normed=True)
H = h1 - h2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, title='imshow: square bins')
plt.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', origin='low',extent=[xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]])
ax = fig.add_subplot(122, title='pcolormesh: actual edges')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xedges, yedges)
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, H)
plt.show()
```

[image: Subtracted histograms]

As one commenter pointed out, it makes sense that these plots are skewed because they're now (100,100) bins instead of the original axes, which were (0,1000),(-100,100). This can be fixed:

```
plt.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest', origin='low')
```

However, the output is then oddly rotated. I can tell because the vague hazy bar should be vertical:

[image: unsquished output]

Answer (score 3):

Two problems.

1. You need to use the same bins for both histograms, else they cannot be subtracted.
2. You cannot subtract the densities, unless you made sure that they refer to the same number of points and the same data range. Because it's unlikely that there is the same number of points, calculate the absolute frequencies instead, which can easily be substracted if they live in the same bins.

Therefore it needs to be

```
h1, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x1, y1, bins=(100,100),normed=False)
h2, _, __ = np.histogram2d(x2, y2, bins=(xedges, yedges), normed=False)
H = h1 - h2
```

When plotting mind that the output array of `np.histogram2d` [needs to be transposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568370/matplotlib-2d-histogram-seems-transposed) before plotting; i.e. `plt.imshow(H.T, ...)` or `plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, H.T, ...)`.

Comment: That actually produced the same output. I'm convinced that I can produce some sort of contour or similar 2d histogram by manipulating H from hist2d enough, but I'd prefer to use the hist2d format for comparison.

It's just sort of mystifying that the histogram functions return all the bins but then they can't plot them again for you.

Comment: No. `hist2d` calculates a histogram and plots it. If you already have histrogrammed data you can plot them with imshow or pcolor(mesh). (Note that you did not actually tell why you don't like the outcome.)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I can remove the binning from the output and get square plots again, but one issue is that they are oddly rotated about 90 degrees. I'll edit the original post an add that tidbit in there, thanks.

Comment: Added a sentence in the answer.